# Filter View on Partial Term Name Across All Vocabs

Tags: views

Hello im sure i used to be able to do this with D6 and Views 2. Struggling to achieve it now.

I was wanting to create a content view that is filtered on partial matches of a term name across ALL my vocabs. Say i filtered on 'science' then the view will show content tagged 'science videos' from my Video Vocab and also, for example 'science chat' from my 'tags' Vocab.

Using D7 and Views 3 i dont seem to have the option to filter on name only ID and ID is limited to one vocab.

Does anyone know if i am missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sorted. Add relationship Taxonomy term: Name in a TERM view and viola

Comment: now if only i could work out how to show the group name in the same View ill be there.